# Support screen Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I was wondering how to add support screen into my Lightswitch application?
Something like this: [Excel Help and How-to](http://img145.imageshack.us/img145/6076/supportq.png)

Of course, I want it to be editable so I can provide Help screen to my clients all the time, and update it with new informations.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Andy Kung's tutorial on creating a similar screen.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/08/27/course-manager-vs-2012-sample-part-6-home-screen-andy-kung.aspx)

The resulting screen will look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is "How to create new screen template" for Lightswitch, what I need is exactly the same thing I posted in linked image of my first post.

Thanks anyway for your response.